# multiple form validation

Tags: jquery, html

On a page i have a form that i need to validate with some kind of a button, however the form can be copied so there's more than one form with the same classid. No problem this could be done through

```
$(button.validate).click(function (){
  $(this.form).validate();    
});
```

validate() functions doesn't work with this operator like the other functions, so i ask is there another way to do this? I cant give each form unique id... i just have a button in the form that is assigned to validate the form that its attached on.

```
function validate(targetform){


    $(targetform).validate({ 

            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {                 
            error.appendTo( element.parent("div").next("div"));   
             }           
       });
    }
```

Html

```
<button onclick="validate($(this).closest('form'))">validate</button>
```

Comment: are the forms going to be open at the same time? i mean the copied and the original?

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the form from each button with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myButtonClass').click(function () {
        var relevantFormID = $(this).closest('form').prop('id');
        ValidateForm(relevantFormID);
    });
}
```

Then, a separate `ValidateForm` function can do all the work:

```
function ValidateForm(targetFormID) {
    $targetForm = $('form[id="' + targetFormID + '"]');
    //Your target form is now available as a jQuery object, all perks included
    //validation goes here
}
```

Comment: the script in the first post should work as well as your answer, however the problem is that, i cant call .validate() function outside of $(document).ready() function

Comment: then isolate your validation to a separate function and pass that function the form id as argument. You can then retrieve the form within the function and take it from there

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'

Comment: Please edit your post with what you've tried, so I can see your code. Thanks.

Comment: relevantFormID doesn't get any value

Comment: make sure the button is inside the form, the form has an id and make sure the click function is inside the $(document).ready() function

Comment: It's like you said, but still: Uncaught ReferenceError: relevantFormId is not defined